# Howto change expired password over JNDI in Active Directory without admin user

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I would like to change password for user in Active Directory using JNDI. The problem is, that this user's password has expired. When I create `InitialDirContext` it gives me immediately an error (`data 773` means password expired):

> javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 -
>   80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext
>   error, data 773, v1db1

I know that IBM LDAP has special bind which addresses this issue, but I could not find something for AD.

Is it possible to change expired password for user without admin account? I would like to provide current and new password and change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I've figured it out:

There a two ways how password in AD can expire:

1. Admin sets it to expired by setting a flag
2. The expiration date has been reached

In the first case password cannot be changed trough LDAP and I will receive  `data 773`. In second case change should be possible.

Comment: Any details how it is possible to change password in the second case w/o admin acc?